# How do I join the following list of series based on series name?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I have two object series, one before and one after, grouped by name.

I generated them from the following code:

```py
beforeseries = dfbefore.groupby('name', dropna=True)['order'].apply(list)
print(beforeseries)
```

```py
afterseries = dfafter.groupby('name', dropna=True)['order'].apply(list)
print(afterseries)
```

Which generate the following outputs:

Beforeseries:

> Name1 [first, second, third]
> Name2 [first, second, third]
> Name_n [first, second, third, fourth]

Afterseries:

> Name1 [fourth, fifth]
> Name2 [fourth, fifth, sixth]
> Name_n [fifth, sixth]

I want to join them so the output looks like the following”

> Name 1 [‘first second third’, ‘fourth fifth’]
> Name 2 [‘first second third’, ‘fourth fifth sixth’]
> Name 3 [‘first second third fourth’, ‘fifth sixth’]

Comment: post a testable data structures suitable  for copy-pasting or generating

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking for code to generate the dataframe that generated the series?

Comment: post a testable `df` and clarify why those 2 series which are expected to be different, are made by the identical operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, seems like you need to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both objects :

```
out = (
    pd.concat([beforeseries, afterseries], axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
        # .squeeze() # uncomment this chain if you need a Series
)
```

Another variant :

```
# to turn off the FutureWarning in `2.1.0`:
# DataFrame.groupby with axis=1 is deprecated.
# Do `frame.T.groupby(...)` without axis instead.

out = (
    pd.concat([beforeseries, afterseries], axis=1)
        .T.groupby(level=0).agg(list).T
)
```

Alternatively, without creating the intermediate Series :

```
keys = ["before", "after"]

out = (
    pd.concat([dfbefore, dfafter], keys=keys, names=["when", None])
        .groupby(by=["name", "when"], sort=False)["order"].agg(" ".join)
        .unstack().agg(list, axis=1)
        # .to_frame("order")
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

           order
name            
A     [v x, o q]
B         [y, r]
C     [w z, p s]
```

Used inputs :

```
dfbefore = pd.DataFrame({"name": list("ACABC"), "order": list("vwxyz")})
beforeseries = dfbefore.groupby("name", dropna=True)["order"].agg(" ".join)

dfafter = pd.DataFrame({"name": list("ACABC"), "order": list("opqrs")})
afterseries  = dfafter.groupby("name", dropna=True)["order"].agg(" ".join)
```